# Git: origin branch won't remove the file that I removed it from cloned branch.

Tags: git

Scenario:

I have a remote git repo for a website, cloned to my local working directory.

When I am working in the cloned repo (master branch),

1. I delete test.html, (*$ git rm test.html*)
2. then commit the change  (*$ git commit -m "Removed test file"*)
3. finally push to remote repo (master)    (*$ git push*)

However, I navigate to the page in browser: http://[website]/test.html, the page still shows. 
It seems test.html yet been deleted. I am pretty sure that I have deleted it in local cloned branch, committed and pushed.

Am I doing anything wrong or missing any step?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pushing to a remote location it will update the repository but won't update the checkout. If you want to update the checkout you have to write a post-receive hook doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing seems right. Step 4 in the process would be to go to your web server and git pull from the remote repo (master).

A simple way to check is to run it show-ref HEAD on the webserver and your local machine. The sha1 should be the same if both are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an addition to bcurren's answer. I do not have comment privileges, hence a new answer)

You have to understand that there are three repositories in play here. First is the local repo on your local machine, second is the remote repo (to which you push your changes). Third is the repo on your **web server**.

Conceptually the repos on your local machine and the web server are like client repos to the remote repo. So once a push is made to the remote repo, a pull has to be made on web server to get the most recent commits (which in your case includes deletion of the file test.html).

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to me that the second and third repos are the same. It's probably not a good idea to do that, but I think that's what OP has.

Comment: Considering that the push did not have any effect on the web server I inferred that there are 3 repos in play here. I am also assuming that he is not playing with multiple branches and forgot to push the branch on which he committed.